# A true if condition is being skipped

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm trying to figure out why this condition is being skipped.. It is a 2d array, it's pretty self explanatory what's being compared. Here's the code first followed by explanation.

```
if ((reversed[i][j] == true) && (circle[i][j] == 'C'))
{
   reversed[i][j] == false;
}
else if (circle[i][j] == 'C')
   reversed[i][j] == true;
```

The problem is that it's skipping the else if EVEN when it's true; I've tested using a cout just before the code where I say:

```
cout<<circle[i][j];
```

and it's showing that it is indeed 'C' this is very weird, I've never seen anything like it. I hope there's something simple I'm missing.

circle is defined as follows:

```
char **circle;

circle = new char *[SIZE];
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
  circle[i] = new char[SIZE];
```

Comment: `circle` should probably be a `std::vector<std::string>`. Don't burden yourself with manual memory management.

Comment: You have an extra `)` at the end of your first line.

Comment: It looks like your assignments aren't actually assignments (== vs =).  It probably IS hitting the else if, it just doesn't look like it.

Comment: By the way, any reasonable compiler will complain about a statement of just `reversed[i][j] == false;` given the chance.

Comment: The memory allocation is not the problem. I have multiple arrays like this that worked, it only seemed to have this issue when I started to check for reversed.

Comment: I know that reversed[i][j] == true; is NOT evaluating because the code following has:  
    if (reversed[i][j])  

and that is not evaluating

Comment: @Deadlypinfish, I never said it was a problem, just that it's extra unnecessary pain and suffering. By manually managing memory, you've now made your code harder to maintain and probably exception-unsafe.

Comment: what's the point of `reversed[i][j]`?

Comment: @Deadlypinfish Do you understand the difference between `=` and `==`?

Comment: @staticx reversed holds boolean values to store whether a vertex is going to be evaluated in reverse. So if regular vertex [i][j] wanted me to move up, the reverse check will determine if I instead move down

Comment: @JohnnyMopp seriously how did it take so long for someone to catch that hahaha, thank you

Comment: Somebody answered this three minutes after you posted the question. That isn't *that* long.

Comment: I'm surprised your compiler didn't catch this.

Comment: @juanchopanza I'm in a computer lab with other people that were like, yeah man that's weird.. And yeah I'm forced to do it on linux so I miss a lot of help from the compiler

Comment: Wow, some computer lab.

Comment: Anyway, if you are using g++ or clang, you can get reasonable errors. For example, `warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]`. Just crank up the warning levels.

Answer (score 7):

Are you sure that you wanted to write

```
if ((reversed[i][j] == true) && circle[i][j] == 'C'))
{
  reversed[i][j] == false;
}
else if (circle[i][j] == 'C')
  reversed[i][j] == true;
```

instead of this?

```
if ((reversed[i][j] == true) && circle[i][j] == 'C')
{
  reversed[i][j] = false; // assignment here
}
else if (circle[i][j] == 'C')
  reversed[i][j] = true;  // assignment here
```

Comment: Typo in the question, I'm sorry about that. I've updated the question

Comment: @Deadlypinfish:  To be explicit, the lines `reversed[i][j] == false;` and `reversed[i][j] == true;` don't do anything and will be removed by the compiler.  In theory the `==` comparison is evaluated and since there is no assignment, the value is tossed away.  Thus the statements have no effect.  Propagating this fact, the `if` and `else if` can be removed also (compiler may not generate code at all).